# How to access global variable in htm page - jtemplate(jquery)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using jtemplate(jquery) , in which i have a htm file as below

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
    <tr class="dark_color">
        <th>
           Offer
        </th>

    </tr>
    {#foreach $T.TransList as record}
    <tr class="{#if ($T.record$index % 2) == 0} white_left {#else} dark_color {#/if}">
           <td class="offer" align="left">
            {$T.record.OfferName}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {#/for}
</table>
```

I am filling data using below code in my aspx page -

```
 $("#jtemplateGrid_" + lastID).setTemplateURL('JTemplate/gridTemplate.htm');
 // process the template          
$("#jtemplateGrid_" + lastID).processTemplate(data)
```

;

Now i want to use global variable in my htm page.
How we can done the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: fyi, it's `HTML`, not `HTM`, and `I`, not `we`

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to send a get parameter with it and split it using JavaScript or whatever you'd like on the page to check up on it or use it.

Not clear on how it could be done otherwise but it is a possibility.